# How to use _iter_ with nested dict generator function to get one key - value pair from two stacks at a time

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, deque

I have a class with **iter** that pops() and yields one item at a time from a deque with letters, S_stack = deque(["a","b","c"]) and a stack with integers, I_stack = ([1,2,3]), and I want to combine it with a function, count_dict, which saves key - value pairs, with S_stack letters as keys and I_stack integers as values to the keys and increases the value +1 if condition. At the moment I'm generating all the items into a nested dict in count_dict through a generator function, generator(). Instead, I'd like to run count_dict() so that each time an item from S_stack and I_stack are popped in **iter**, for instance 'a' from S_stack and 1 from I_stack and add it to nested_dict in count_dict before the next items, "b" and 2 are popped. So running count_dict through **iter** one element at time with next function or similar.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import collections
from collections import deque


I_stack = deque([1,2,3])
S_stack = deque(["a","b","c"])
def generator():


    for i in range(len(I_stack)):
        for j in range(len(S_stack)):


            yield (S_stack[j], I_stack[j])

        break


def count_dict(t):

    h = 1
    try:
        while True:
            if h == 1:
                k,v = (yield)
                v = v +1

                t['Left'][k]['h'] = v
                print t

            else:

                k,v = (yield)


                t['Left'][k]['h'] = v#  [k] = v
                print t



    except GeneratorExit:
        pass



#tally = defaultdict(int)
tally = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
c = count_dict(tally)
c.send(None)

#print [c.send(val) for val in generator1()]
do_all = deque(maxlen=0).extend
do_all(c.send(val) for val in generator())
for k in sorted(tally):
    print k, tally[k]

class StackHandler(list):
    """ a subclass for generating sequences in stacks"""
    def __init__(self, stop_key, list):
        self.stop_key = stop_key

        self.I_stack = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
        self.S_stack = deque(["a","b","c"])
        super(StackHandler, self).__init__(list)



    def __iter__(self):

        while True:
            try:
                item = list.pop(self)


                self.S_stack.append(self.I_stack.popleft())
                self.I_stack.pop()
                self.S_stack.pop()




                yield self.I_stack



                if item is self.stop_key:
                    break
                else: 
                    yield item
            except:
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    I_stack = deque([1,2,3,4])

    ls = [
        {

            'stop_key' : 5,
            'stack_ls' : I_stack
            },
        {

            'stop_key' : 'c',
            'stack_ls' : deque(['a','b','c','d'])
            }
        ]



    for i in ls:
        ls = StackHandler(i['stop_key'],
                                      i['stack_ls'])

        n = 4
        print "test", i
        for j in range(n):
            for item in ls:
                print '(j:%i) %s' % (j, item)
            print '-' * 20
        print '\n', 

# Desired output:

#Run 1 - "a", 1 , S_stack, I_stack
#Run 2 - "b", 2
#Run 3 - "c", 3
# and so on
```

These are stored in nested dict t,  t['Left'][k]['h'] = v, for instance ;

defaultdict( at 0x48c6050>, {'Left': defaultdict(, {'a': {'h': 2}})})
in count_dict()

Comment: `generator` looks like `itertools.product`, btw. otherwise, it's not clear to me what you are trying to do, and am guessing you have some sort of XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. one problem: ints are immutable, so passing an int somewhere can never be by reference.

Comment: At the moment generator() is temporary solution used to generate the nested dict t in count_dict() with key - value pairs from S_stack and I_stack. I want to replace the generator() function with the _iter__ op, which pops one item from each stack a time, or run count_dict in __iter__ so that each stack, S_stack and I_stack are popped once, for instance "a" and 1 are popped and sent to count_dict and added as key-value pair in t. When that's completed the next _iter_ process is done for "b" and 2 and they are sent to count_dict, and so on repeatedly until the stacks are empty.

Comment: I understand the code description. What's not clear is, why is the code written this way? (also, `generator` is the name of the built-in generator type, you shouldn't use it for a variable name). I read your generator wrong, but it generates the same output as `itertools.izip(S_stack, I_stack)` if that helps you reduce the code.

Comment: @corley: there is no built-in generator type...